# Fatal error: Call to undefined method codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please help me. I've tried to solve it, but what is the problem in my code? This is my first time to encounter this error. I really need help, please.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method supp_model::getsuppid() in C:\wamp\www\minimart\application\controllers\minimart.php on line 19
```

Here is my library:

```
class minimart extends CI_controller { //myclass


function __construct()
     {

    parent::__construct();
    }



    function supplier()
    {
        $this->load->model('supp_model');
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $mini['allrecords']= $this->supp_model->getsuppid($id); //this line give me an error
        $this->load->view('view_supplier.php', $mini); 
    }
```

My Model:

```
class supp_model extends CI_Model {



    function getsuppid($id) //the function exist
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('supplier_table');
        $this->db->where('supplier_code ', $id);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        $result = $q->result();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly you need to make first letter of class name **capital** It should be like **class Minimart** and **class Supp_model**

Comment: Add the constructor as  { parent::__construct(); }

Comment: Thank you for the Advise @NarendraSisodia I just rename it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database('default', true); 
    }
 function supplier()
    {
        $this->load->model('supp_model',true);
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $mini['allrecords']= $this->supp_model->getsuppid($id); 
        $this->load->view('view_supplier.php', $mini); 
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou! so much @soul :D now i could proceed ;)

Comment: @MilbhenBars accept the answer and upvote if it had helped you